# Dart: How to reference a function with arguments without invoking it?

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I reference a dart function with arguments without invoking it?
It's easy to reference a function without parameters but when I pass a parameter I can't stop it from being invoked.

```
void main() {
  Function refA = funA; // Doesn't invoke
  Function refB = funB("funB"); // It prints "funB"
}

funA() {
  print("funA");
}

funB(String string) {
  print(string);
}
```

It's OK for `refA` but how do I do this for `refB`?

Comment: `Function refB = ()=>funB("funB");`

Comment: @LonelyWolf I was looking for something exactly like this, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When you put the brackets after the Function's name it executes the function and returns the value of that execution. Try that with `funA`

```
Function refA = funA();
```

it will get called. to reference `funB()` you would do this:

```
Function refB = funB;
```

you can then call the function like the following:

```
refB('Text');
```